# Je dois / devrais leur dire de

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour,

> Du coin de l’œil, j’aperçois A et B qui essaient d’ouvrir l’armoire
> fermée à clé. Je **dois** leur dire de ne pas toucher aux objets, mais je
> laisse tomber. Et s’ils trouvaient quelque chose d’intéressant ?
>
> Du coin de l’œil, j’aperçois A et B qui essaient d’ouvrir l’armoire
> fermée à clé. Je **devrais** leur dire de ne pas toucher aux objets, mais
> je laisse tomber. Et s’ils trouvaient quelque chose d’intéressant ?

"Je dois leur dire" = "Il faut que je leur dise".

"Je devrais leur dire" = "Je dois leur dire X, mais je ne le ferai pas".

Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Ta compréhension est correcte, néanmoins je trouve que les deux exemples fonctionnent. Evidemment la seconde phrase rend la nuance inutile, elle rend la suite des événements explicite. Mais si il n'y a que la première phrase, effectivement l'emploi du conditionnel dans celle-ci suggère que le sujet ne fera pas pas ce qu'il devrait faire, et le présent suggère qu'il le fera.

Notons que réciproquement on peut également employer le conditionnel même si l'action se réalise finalement:

> Je devrais leur dire de ne pas toucher aux objets. Et c'est ce que je fais. Ils ne le prennent pas bien et se montrent menaçants.

Le conditionnel vient ici atténuer le côté impératif de "devoir".

Je dois leur dire = j'ai la consigne, le devoir, l'obligation de leur dire

Je devrais leur dire > C'est sans doute la meilleure chose à faire, bien que cela ne soit pas ma responsabilité.

Comment: Merci. Mais pourquoi utiliser le conditionnel dans la dernière phrase si l'action se réalise - tout de suite ou quelque temps après ?

Comment: Ah, parce qu'ici il a un autre sens : atténiation de "je dois"

Comment: Bonne remarque, j'ai édité ma réponse.